# Android NDK tries to build with sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/ but gnu-libstdc++ doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-ndk, llvm

I'm trying to build an old Android project which has native components.

When I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED
Build myappNative x86
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libmyappNative.so
FAILED: : && /Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android16 --gcc-toolchain=/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -fPIC -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -fno-addrsig -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -static-libstdc++ -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -Wl,-soname,libmyappNative.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libmyappNative.so CMakeFiles/myappNative.dir/src/main/cpp/src/com_myapp_system_Native.cpp.o CMakeFiles/myappNative.dir/src/main/cpp/src/sha256.c.o  -llog -latomic -lm "/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a" && :
clang++: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Which is pretty obvious:

`error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a'`

When I go to `/Users/Can/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/` there are only the following:

- `llvm-libc++`
- `llvm-libc++abi`
- `system`

There is no such `gnu-libstdc++` directory. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** For the meantime, I've switched back to old NDK r17c upon Alex Cohn's suggestion. It works, though that NDK is obsolete and this is just a temporary workaround, not a long term solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since that project was released, NDK [has dropped gnustl](https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18). You can still download NDK r.17 or earlier, or you can change your project to use **libc++_static** instead.

Comment: How can I do it? I've tried googling Cmake gradle libc++_static though couldn't find an example. There are only examples for mk files.

Comment: Which example were you looking for? Find references to gnustl in your project.

Comment: The only references to `gnustl` are only from outputs/build artifacts. There aren't any references from my code or config files to it.

Comment: *references to `gnustl` are only from outputs/build artifacts* – are there some  prebuilt binaries?

Comment: Another option: maybe your project uses a really old Android Gradle plugin? Try to open it in AS 3.5 and it will probably prompt you to upgrade your Gradle plugin.

Comment: Regarding former of the two comments: nope, not prebuilt, just the ones from build output files. Regarding the latter: I have AS 3.4.1 and when I check for updates it says I'm on the latest version.

Answer (score -2):

The following commands can be used to install the missing packages in `linux` based systems.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Comment: I'm not on Linux.